# store json objects together in node.js before sending request to backend

Tags: javascript, arrays, json, node.js, javascript-objects

I have a log file , from which I am parsing relevant fields and saving them in a javascript object like below

```
var jsonArg1 = new Object();
    jsonArg1.url = arr[13];
    jsonArg1.method = arr[12];
```

the above object is just for a single line in log file. I need to aggregate all the lines from the log files before i make REST call to elasticsearch APIs as a single document.

So how can I aggregate all lines of the logs so that I could put them as a json document to my backend ??

Edit :

Adding some more code on the array method suggested in the comments:

```
var pluginArrayArg = new Array();
    pluginArrayArg.push(jsonArg1);      

    var data = function(){
    for(var i=0;i<pluginArrayArg.length;i++){
        return '{"create":{"_index":"test2", "_type":"logs"}}'+'\n'+JSON.stringify(pluginArrayArg[i]);
}
}();
```

I am passing the data string as payload for my post request in  elasticsearch index.

Comment: Concat arrays http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_concat_array.asp

Comment: How does the "backend" expect these lines of the logs to be constructed? That will determine how you "aggregate" them.

Comment: @VladimirM thanks for the suggestions.  seems to work :)